# How can I create variable that is array of values of variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, javascript-objects

I want to store values of name, selectedDay and selectedMovie into reservationData. Then, I want reservationData to pass in ajax as a data so I can get it in my Controller, read from them and insert them into my database

This is my code:

```
var reservationData = {"name": name, "selectedMovie": selectedMovie, "selectedDay": selectedDay};
console.log(reservationData);

var confirmReservation = $('.confirm-reservation');

confirmReservation.on('click', function(){
  
  $.ajax({
    url: '/drupal/movie-reservation',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    data:{result: JSON.stringify(reservationData)},
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
  });
```

Everytime my name, selectedMovie and selectedDay gain their value I want that value to be stored in reservationData as well. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not very clear what you are saying, what problem are you trying to correct

Comment: Im sorry. Ok so, I want to store values of name, selectedDay and selectedMovie into reservationData. Then, I want reservationData to pass in ajax as a data so I can get it in my Controller, read from them and insert them into my database.

Comment: @MajaB Please put that comment of yours into your original question.

Answer (score 2):

Your current reservationData variable is an object, not an array. You will keep updating/overwriting the same properties. So you will need an array to push these reservationData onto.

Comment: Thanks Dean ! WIll try it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by defining `arrReservationData` as an array containing objects.

Each click on `.confirm-reservation` will send a new `objNewReservationData` object via ajax to your controller.
The returned result object will be pushed to `arrReservationData`.

```
var arrReservationData = [],
var objNewReservationData = {
  "name": name, 
  "selectedMovie": selectedMovie, 
  "selectedDay": selectedDay
},
confirmReservation = $('.confirm-reservation');

confirmReservation.on('click', function(){  
  $.ajax({
    url: '/drupal/movie-reservation',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    data: {result: JSON.stringify(objNewReservationData)},
    success: function(data){
      let objResponse = {
        "name": data.name, 
        "selectedMovie": data.selectedMovie, 
        "selectedDay": data.selectedDay
      };
      arrReservationData.push(objResponse);
      // do stuff with arrReservationData, like storing in a database
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this! And I think this is exactly answer to my question :)

Comment: @MajaB Feel free to mark it as accepted answer incase :)

Comment: It's not doing the job. When I debug reservationData, it says it is null...

Comment: @MajaB Have a look at the updated answer please. I hope i understood your querstion  better now.